# Existence of an infinite finitely generated $p$-group with nontrivial intersection of nontrivial subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there an infinite finitely generated (non-cyclic) $p$-group $G$ such that the intersection of all nontrivial subgroups of $G$ is a nontrivial subgroup?

Comment: [question origin](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879196/a-persisting-element-in-all-subgroups/879254?noredirect=1#comment1814479_879254)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example is given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102208/finitely-generated-infinite-p-group). And here are some more words to make MO happy.

Comment: thanks. there's a simple workaround for leaving MO unhappy,